# temporary cassandra write timeout exception on increasing load

Tags: cassandra, timeout

We have a 5 node cluster with each one of config 128 GB RAM, 24 core CPU. Suppose for 100k writes per sec, there are no write timeout exceptions, but as soon as load is increased to 125k or more, timeout exceptions start to creep in. These exceptions stay for a min or two and then eventually cluster stabilizes. Then it will continue to work fine, without any exceptions.

So I need to understand, what is the reason for timeout exceptions during sudden spike in load?

Is that cache is already full, and all of a sudden load increased so write exceptions started to occur. And if thats the case, then should I decrease memtable flush time from 10 to 5 seconds. Will this has any other implications?

Answer (score 0):

The WriteTimeOut exceptions are due to overloading of the nodes i.e. under high ingest rate a node has to do more work i.e. more CPU/IO resources usage which means it cant complete the operation in specified timeout period leading to writeTimeOut exceptions. I don't think reducing Memtable flush period will help in this situation (it might even make it wrose as you will be doing disk IO more frequently causing more resource usage). You either need to add more nodes to the cluster (if you are going to see these spikes too often) or need some way in your application to throttle your writes to C* (if you can afford to do that). Note that C* has something called Hinted Handoff which means coordinator node will store the row mutation for your write if it finds a replica node was overloaded and will try to replay it later. But this stored hint is not counted towards CONSISTENCY_LEVEL (except when you are using ANY). There is very good DataStax blog post about hinted handoff which you can check [here](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/modern-hinted-handoff).

So C* is doing its best to handle these spikes but if its persistent issue then you need to add more nodes or throttle your writes.